# NVarchar max datatype having unicode characters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've created a column which is of datatype nvarchar(max) and while i'm filling with data it's holding only 150 characters and cutting off the remaining data as stated below.

```
SampleColumn(nvarchar(max),null)
```

Below is the data i'm inserting into it.

> Alpha;Animal Health;NIBR;Noratine Vaconine and Diagnooptimal;OTC Over the Counter;Pharma China;Pharma Development;Pharma japan;Pharma LaCan;Sandoz;pharma europe;pharma inida;pharma apac

But taking below characters i.e. 150 characters.

> Alpha;Animal Health;NIBR;Noratine Vaconine and Diagnooptimal;OTC Over the Counter;Pharma China;Pharma Development;Pharma japan;Pharma LaCan;Sandoz;pha

What could be the reason here by taking only 150 char's, if it's correct how can i allow more than 150 characters into my column?

Comment: Your column will not truncate the data in a nvarchar(max) until the length is 2gb. How are you viewing this data or inserting it? Also, you should consider normalizing your data instead of using delimited strings like this. You are violating 1NF by putting more than 1 value in a single intersection.

Comment: How exactly are you inserting the data?

Comment: Try this select: `SELECT LEN(SampleColumn) FROM SampleTable`. What does it returns?

Comment: Lamak - Inserting data as string like reading the data from the column and concatenating with the new data and again updating to the column.

Comment: Sean - Inserting data as string like reading the data from the column and concatenating with the new data and again updating to the column.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using SQL Management Studio to see the data. This is its limitation. See configuration options.

Comment: Yes using management studio, but while other column having more than 1000 characters i can see it in column why can't this?

Comment: Use `SUBSTRING` to show parts of the string. Or write small program in C# to see whole value.

Answer (score 0):

Probably SSMS?

Try right click into your query window, open the options, set the "Text" max length to 8192 (maximum allowed here) and re-execute...